# Error while building aosp launcher in android studio

Tags: android, android-source, android-launcher

```
 Task :IconLoader:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
/home/vineel/Desktop/Launcher3/iconloaderlib/src_full_lib/com/android/launcher3/icons/SimpleIconCache.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
            int index = mUserSerialMap.indexOfKey(user.getIdentifier());
                                                      ^
  symbol:   method getIdentifier()
  location: variable user of type UserHandle
/home/vineel/Desktop/Launcher3/iconloaderlib/src_full_lib/com/android/launcher3/icons/SimpleIconCache.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
            mUserSerialMap.put(user.getIdentifier(), serial);
                                   ^
  symbol:   method getIdentifier()
  location: variable user of type UserHandle
/home/vineel/Desktop/Launcher3/iconloaderlib/src_full_lib/com/android/launcher3/icons/SimpleIconCache.java:87: error: cannot find symbol
        return info.isInstantApp();
                   ^
  symbol:   method isInstantApp()
  location: variable info of type ApplicationInfo
3 errors
```

got this error while building aosp launcher in android I have tried to remove the lines that caused the error but got this new error

```
Directory '/home/vineel/Desktop/Launcher3/build/extracted-include-protos/aosp' specified for property '$9' does not exist.
```

Comment: Most of the AOSP apps are not designed to be built independently as Android SDK apps. They are meant to be built as part of a full firmware build.

Answer (score 0):

@vineet how did u tackle this problem? Were you able to build it Gradle
independently?

@CommonsWare, I understand..however, could you clarify why then the Launcher is made gradle compatible? I mean everything else is set right in Gradle build files so as to work independently without AOSP